# Macro recorded on another sheet: "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro in Excel. When I try to run it on a new worksheet I get the error message:

> "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified value is out of range"

When I click "debug" it highlights:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12`

I tried replacing "Chart 1" with `ActiveChart` throughout the code, but that hasn't worked.

```
Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$B$496"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table1", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable10", DefaultVersion:=7
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Program Area")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable10").PivotFields("Payment Amount"), "Sum of Payment Amount", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Sum of Payment Amount"). _
        Orientation = xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable10").PivotFields("Payment Amount"), "Sum of Payment Amount", xlSum
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$B$8")
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelBestFit)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowPercentage = True
    Selection.ShowSeriesName = True
    Selection.ShowSeriesName = False
    Selection.ShowCategoryName = True
    Selection.Separator = " "
    Selection.Separator = "" & Chr(13) & ""
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = _
        "Edmond J. Safra Philanthropic Foundation (Vaduz)" & Chr(13) & "Donations: DATE" & Chr(13) & "GRAND TOTAL"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Edmond J. Safra Philanthropic Foundation (Vaduz)" & Chr(13) & "Donations: DATE" & Chr(13) & "GRAND TOTAL"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 49).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 40).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(41, 9).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(50, 16).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(50, 16).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(66, 11).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(66, 11).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
        .NameFarEast = "Times New Roman"
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveChart.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .ChartSize = xlScreenSize
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).LeaderLines.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Left = 136.5
    Selection.Top = 34
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.Left = 112.591
    Selection.Top = 54
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: it means that `Chart 1` does not exist on the active sheet. `Chart1` may have been the name of the chart when it was recorded but now it has a different name.

Comment: I've tried replacing it with "ActiveChart" but so far that hasn't worked. Is there a way to make it a variable and pick any chart on the worksheet?

Comment: @EF3328 you can replace it with its Index, but you have to be sure the index is right, or else you'll get the same error. if there is only one shape in your active sheet you can use `ActiveSheet.Shapes(0).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12` and you can do the same for the next line.
you can loop using `for` through all shapes to get their indexes (or search for the chart one)